# Speed up an SQL query with join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm hoping to get some help on how to speed up an SQL query.
To give you some context, here's an outline of the related db structure:

1. table instruments - instruments have isin, trading_venue, start_trading_date, end_trading_date;
   one and the same instrument can trade on multiple venues, with varying start and end trading dates;
   has an index on isin and the trading dates;
2. view instrument_start_end_dates - in this view, for each instrument isin I get the earliest start_trading_date and the latest end_trading date, across all trading venues;
3. table trades - each trade has a date_time column with a timestamp and the isin of the traded instrument; has an index on the date_time column and the isin column;

What I'm trying to accomplish - get all trades, where the date of the trade is between the start and end trading date for the respective instrument.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM execs_prop e
JOIN isin_start_end_dates ised on ised.isin = e.isin_cusip
WHERE DATE(e.date_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') = '2024-03-04'
  AND DATE(e.date_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') >= ised.start_trading_date 
  AND DATE(e.date_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') <= ised.end_trading_date
ORDER BY e.date_time;
```

The query is returning the desired results, but it's slow - usually it takes around 8 minutes.

Here is the EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
"Gather Merge  (cost=1348478.40..1431695.31 rows=713238 width=159) (actual time=199969.600..199999.190 rows=26784 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=1347478.38..1348369.92 rows=356619 width=159) (actual time=199727.735..199728.562 rows=8928 loops=3)"
"        Sort Key: e.date_time"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2664kB"
"        Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2949kB"
"        Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2359kB"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1191253.51..1258520.93 rows=356619 width=159) (actual time=189405.742..199719.816 rows=8928 loops=3)"
"              Hash Cond: ((e.isin_cusip)::bpchar = instruments.isin)"
"              Join Filter: ((date(timezone('UTC'::text, e.date_time)) >= (min(instruments.first_trdg_date))) AND (date(timezone('UTC'::text, e.date_time))   Parallel Seq Scan on execs_prop e  (cost=0.00..53271.59 rows=3742 width=138) (actual time=0.094..279.061 rows=14837 loops=3)"
"                    Filter: (date(timezone('UTC'::text, date_time)) = '2024-03-04'::date)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 583789"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=1147913.49..1147913.49 rows=2360642 width=21) (actual time=189392.680..189392.683 rows=9132958 loops=3)"
"                    Buckets: 65536 (originally 65536)  Batches: 256 (originally 64)  Memory Usage: 3585kB"
"                    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.56..1124307.07 rows=2360642 width=21) (actual time=1.361..184799.653 rows=9132958 loops=3)"
"                          Group Key: instruments.isin"
"                          ->  Index Only Scan using idx_instruments_isin_first_last_date on instruments  (cost=0.56..996661.48 rows=13871889 width=21) (actual time=1.156..179268.392 rows=13498015 loops=3)"
"                                Heap Fetches: 26547906"
"Planning Time: 0.409 ms"
"Execution Time: 200001.209 ms"
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Interim update 1: I did the following:

1. VACUUM FULL to the instruments table;
2. Deleted the current index in the execs_prop table and added a new one (where the date is stored in UTC timezone).

This has brought execution times from 8 minutes down to 3 minutes.

I also noticed that I'm joining the execs_prop table to a dynamic view isin_start_end_dates (by dynamic I mean that it's generated every time and scans the entire instruments table). I'm planning to switch to a materialized view and see if this further improves run times. Will report back with more info.

Comment: Have you indexed the relevant columns?

Comment: Yes: 

idx_execs_prop_date_isin ON public.execs_prop USING btree (date_time, isin) idx_instruments_isin_first_last_date ON public.instruments USING btree (isin, first_trdg_date, last_trdg_date)

Comment: Based on the "heap fetches", you really need to vacuum "instruments".

Comment: That plan looks mangled or incomplete.  How can you have a hash join with only one child node?

Comment: Could you share the complete DDL for all tables and indexes involved? In plain text, as an update of your question.

Answer (score 4):

I did notice one thing right away.

Whenever you have a cast from DATETIME to DATE for a comparison and there was an index for the DATETIME column, you should explore whether you can write the query to avoid the cast. *(Hint: this is almost always possible!)* This can dramatically improve performance because the values resulting from the cast no longer match the values stored in the index, making the index effectively worthless for the original query.

For example, we see this:

```
 DATE(e.date_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') = '2024-03-04'
```

But it will almost certainly be better to write the comparison to check a range covering the full day, using a "half open" exclusive upper bound for the *next day*, like this:

```
e.date_time >= '2024-03-04' AND e.date_time < '2024-03-05'
```

Now the original values in the column are unmodified, so the query can still use the index.

The exception is I don't have knowledge on how your values are stored relative to the `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` clause (and this is one reason you should generally store the values in the database in UTC in the first place... to avoid forcing yourself to write potentially index-voiding expressions).

---

Really, this advice can generalize to *any function call* for *any column type* and with *any predicate (comparison)*, because even if indexes and dates are not involved the query will still need to run the function for *every row in the source data* before it can know if the row does or does not match the predicate. Eliminate the function call for per-row data and the query can potentially run faster... sometimes **much** faster.

Comment: Looks like I'm storing the date-times at local time (UTC + 3)

Comment: @Selim if (and only if!) this is always true, you can make a corresponding adjustment  to the date literals in my example to get the desired results.

Comment: I am experimenting from the ground up. The first part of the query, where I get all trades for a specific date is very quick - takes less than 500ms. But when the JOIN is added, without the further checks for start and end trading dates - execution times go to 3 minutes. Looking at the counts - some 40,000 trades are joined to some 9 million instruments. Will come back with more info.

Answer (score 1):

Please try my code :-

```
SELECT e.*
FROM execs_prop e
JOIN (
    SELECT isin, MIN(start_trading_date) AS min_start_trading_date, MAX(end_trading_date) AS max_end_trading_date
    FROM instrument_start_end_dates
    GROUP BY isin
) AS ised ON ised.isin = e.isin_cusip
WHERE DATE(e.date_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') = '2024-03-04'
  AND e.date_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' >= ised.min_start_trading_date
  AND e.date_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' <= ised.max_end_trading_date
ORDER BY e.date_time;
```